# Como mostrar datos de 2 tablas en un <select>

Tags: php, mysql

tengo 2 tablas
cuenta1 y cuenta2

cuenta1 con las columnas[codigo_cuenta1] y [nombre_cuenta1]

cuenta2 con las columnas[codigo_cuenta2] y [nombre_cuenta2]

necesito de su ayuda para que se muestren en el select los datos de cuenta1 y cuenta2

aca el codigo:

```html
<?php

if(!isset($conexion)){
  include ("conexion.php");
}

$query = "SELECT codigo_cuenta1, nombre_cuenta1 FROM cuenta1 ";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

?>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <label for="cbx_cuenta1" class="control-label">Seleccionar Cuenta1</label>
                      <select name="cbx_cuenta1" id="cbx_cuenta1" class="form-control"  required title="Debe seleccionar una cuenta">
                      <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                      <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['codigo_cuenta1']; ?>"><?php echo $row["codigo_cuenta1"] .". ". utf8_encode($row["nombre_cuenta1"]); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yo preguntaría, ¿por qué tienes dos tablas gemelas? ¿por qué no organizas todo en una sola tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) en tu consulta y problema resuelto. Solo deberías cambiar tu código dejándolo algo así:

```
<?php

if(!isset($conexion)){
  include ("conexion.php");
}

$query = "(SELECT codigo_cuenta1 AS codigo, nombre_cuenta1 as nombre FROM cuenta1) UNION (SELECT codigo_cuenta2 AS codigo, nombre_cuenta2 AS nombre FROM cuenta2)";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

?>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <label for="cbx_cuenta1" class="control-label">Seleccionar Cuenta1</label>
                      <select name="cbx_cuenta1" id="cbx_cuenta1" class="form-control"  required title="Debe seleccionar una cuenta">
                      <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                      <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['codigo_cuenta1']; ?>"><?php echo $row["codigo_cuenta1"] .". ". utf8_encode($row["nombre_cuenta1"]); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
```

**Importante** Los campos que vas a unir de ambas tablas deben tener el mismo nombre. De lo contrario no funcionará. Yo en este caso hice uso de alias. Saludos!

Comment: me funciono muy bien ,muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías preparar previamente un array de salida unico con los datos de ambas consultas:

```
    $sale = [];
$sale['cod_cuenta'] = [];
$sale['nombre_cuenta'] = [];


$a = $db->query("SELECT codigo_cuenta1, nombre_cuenta1 FROM cuenta1");
$b = $db->query("SELECT codigo_cuenta2, nombre_cuenta2 FROM cuenta2");

while($row = $a->fetch_array()){
    array_push($sale['cod_cuenta'], $row['codigo_cuenta1']);
    array_push($sale['nombre_cuenta'], $row['nombre_cuenta1']);
}
while($row = $b->fetch_array()){
    array_push($sale['cod_cuenta'], $row['codigo_cuenta2']);
    array_push($sale['nombre_cuenta'], $row['nombre_cuenta2']);
}
```

ya luego recorres es ese array para generar las opciones de tu selector, puede haber algo más elegante, pero es lo que se me ocurre ahora. Saludos